# Laravel Delete Method: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233:

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I tried to delete the cart from a list. When I tried to delete it, it shows an Error. Below here is my code:

Web.php

```
Route::post('cart/delete/{id}','ProductController@deleteCart');
```

blade.php

```
<a href="{{ url('/cart/delete',$row->id) }}" class="remove_item">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
</a>
    
<form action="{{ url('/cart/delete',$row->id)}}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
    {!! Form::hidden('id',$row->id) !!}
</form>
```

Controller.php

```
public function deleteCart($id){
    $cart = Cart::find($id);
    $cart->destroy();
    return Redirect::to('/shop-cart');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the following line of code:

```
Route::post('cart/delete/{id}','ProductController@deleteCart');
```

into:

```
Route::get('cart/delete/{id}','ProductController@deleteCart');
```

Reason for this error is sending a GET request to a POST route. In your code you are sending a GET request by calling a URL.

```
<a href="{{ url('/cart/delete',$row->id) }}" class="remove_item">
   <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
</a>
```

---

Or otherwise if you want to keep the route as it is (as a POST route) just use the following code and make some adjustments accordingly:

```
<form  action="{{ url('/cart/delete') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
    {!! Form::hidden('id', $row->id) !!}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And it is better to modify the route as follows as the `'/{id}'`  part is not needed as we are sending the id along with the POST request:

```
Route::post('cart/delete','ProductController@deleteCart');
```

Import Http\Request into your controller using:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

And update your controller function as follows:

```
public function deleteCart(Request $request){
    $cart = Cart::find($request['id']);
    $cart->destroy();
    return Redirect::to('/shop-cart'); 
}
```

But for this scenario GET route seems a good choice to avoid complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `a href` link, because it will send GET request, instead of POST. Add submit button to the form:

```
<form  action="{{ url('/cart/delete/'.$row->id) }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
    {!! Form::hidden('id', $row->id) !!}
    {!! Form::submit('delete') !!}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error say that there is no route like the one you try to call.  you have a route like this in your route file : `/cart/delete/{id}` where expects an id, and you call this from your form `/cart/delete?id=theid`

Fix

Change this from your submit url :  `/cart/delete',$row->id)`

To this: `/cart/delete/{{$row->id}}`

Comment: I used this `href="{{ url('/cart/delete/'.$row->id) }}"` but still getting same Error

Comment: btw your 'submission button' must be inside your form and just submit the form you dont need the <a> element

Comment: also try to change your `destroy` to `delete`